# ExactTarget Import Subcribers to list

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, c#

Hi i'm new to exact target api what i'm trying to implement is import subscribers to list using API. i couldn't find a way to implement that.
i only found add one subscriber to list like this using FuelSDK

```
var parameters = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"appSignature", config.AppSignature},
    {"clientId", config.ClientId},
    {"clientSecret", config.ClientSecret},
    {"soapEndPoint", config.SoapEndPoint},
    {"sandbox", config.Sandbox}
};
var client = new ET_Client(parameters);
ET_Subscriber subscriber = new ET_Subscriber
{
    AuthStub = client,
    Attributes = attributes,
    EmailAddress = email
};
subscriber.Post();
```

how to i import subscribers list?

Comment: Do you have to use the API, or can you use the FTP file drop?  And is it to a List, or a Data Extension?